# Cannot transliterate character between character sets

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5, dbeaver

I'm updating data in column [S.STATUS] and get an error:

> SQL Error [335544565] [22018]: arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation; Cannot transliterate character between character sets [SQLState:22018, ISC error code:335544565]'

I'm using DBeaver 6.0.2 and DB is Firebird 2.5.

```
Column Name, Data Type, Charset, Length 
STATUS, SMALLINT, [NULL], 5
```

I've tried to update multiple rows, single row, cast (S.STATUS as SMALINT) etc.

```
UPDATE Table S
SET  S.STATUS = 3
WHERE S.ID = 580864
```

Now [S.STATUS] = 9, I want to change it to [S.STATUS] = 3.

@Edit

Probably the problem is that S.STATUS is primary key in other table [Table2]:
'Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "Table" on table "Table2"; Problematic key value is ("ID" = 3) [SQLState:23000, ISC error code:335544665]

Comment: I think this reference material addresses your issue: http://firebirdfaq.org/faq79/

Comment: The error itself indicates a problem with character sets of string values, and given the values in your code are all numerical, the problem is elsewhere, possibly caused by a historic problem with another column in your table and format versions applying a character set transliteration that is invalid because the data stored is not valid for the target character set. You will need to post a [mcve], or consider posting your question on the firebird-support mailing list as this will likely need troubleshooting, and stack overflow isn't really suitable for that.